# Changing the design of the report at runtime in ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

can i change the design of the report in ireport at runtime.

to be more specific and clear, what if i want the appearance of a table depends on the data comes from the Database at runtime, if a certain value exists then this table will appear in the report, otherwise i don't want it to exist.

is that possible?

for e.g.:

```
select Field_1, Field_2, Field_3 
from CSG_table where xxxKey1 = "a_certain_value" and xxxKey2 = "a_cartain_value"
```

what if the key xxxKey1 doesn't exists in the Database, so the dataset will be empty (but actually i've already added the table which gets its data from the DB using this query), so if the ireport doesn't allow me to change the design at runtime the table will appear empty and i don't want that!!

Comment: Are you really asking about GUI designer (not about the JasperReports API)?

Comment: @AlexK i think you didn't understand my question, do i have a control on ireport components at runtime so i can control what to be added in the output file (as PDF). i think this is related to jasperReports API, isn't it?

Comment: The *iReport* is just a GUI designer for constructing report's templates

Comment: You can attempt to solve this task without *Java* or with help of *Java* code. Your question is unclear for me

Comment: i found something called DynamicJaper.  It creates reports dynamically, defining at runtime the columns.. etc. i'll check it.

Comment: that's why am asking @AlexK do i need an external code to control this or the jaspersoft studio gives me an internal programming which allows me to control on the components :)

Comment: With help of *DynamicJasper API* or *DynamicReports API* or *JasperReports API* you can build the report dynamically

Comment: You can try to use the *jrxml* file for solving task. With help of *Table* component you can hide columns based on conditions (with some limitations)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106575/discussion-between-bdeveloper-and-alex-k).